# Foreign Key Annotation in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, annotations, foreign-keys

I have two tables as

```
State(StateID int,StateName string)

City(CityID int,StateID int,CityName string)
```

I am working on MVC4 with code first approach.The code,i am using for **State** and **City** Model is -

**For State:**

```
[Key]

public int StateID{get;set;}

public string StateName{get;set;}
```

**For City:**

```
[Key]
public int CityID{get;set;}


[ForeignKey("State")]
public string StateID{get;set;}
public virtual State State{get;set;}
```

This code is creating a foreignkey for StateID of State Table.All i wanted is working but as i am new in MVC i got the following code is also doing the same thing.

```
[ForeignKey("StateID")]
public string Stateid{get;set;}
public virtual State StateID{get;set;}
```

It made me lil confuse about what is the correct way for doing...We should pass Model Class name in **ForeignKey Annotation** i.e. **State** or it should be Property i.e. **StateID**
I went through various questions already asked here regarding this Annotation.But i am still not sure about the difference of above codes.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using the `ForeignKey` attribute, you pass the name of navigation property the foreign key should point to.

So, in your first example you have:

```
[ForeignKey("State")]
public string StateID { get; set; }

public virtual State State { get; set; } // This is your navigation property
```

This is the correct way to use the attribute. The `"State"` you passed into the attribute corresponds to the navigation property name.

In your second example, your navigation property was named `StateID`, which is why `[ForeignKey("StateID")]` also worked in that instance.

Take a look at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation for more information.