# 2 tables in Local DB in MVC using a foreign key to interact - Error, returns "The property cannot be configured as a navigation property

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, foreign-keys

So my teammates and I are building a website that aggregates textbook prices from different textbook websites (we aren't dynamically getting the prices from the websites themselves, but for the purposes of the school project we are in, we are just randomly entering them in).

So I've got two tables in my database Book1 - a "Books" table and a "Prices" table. I have a foreign key in my [Prices table (screenshot of design view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYdB2.png) that relates back to my [Books table (screenshot of design view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDb3t.png).

The ISBN field of our Prices table is a foreign key to the ISBN field of our Books table.

We believe we've set everything else up correctly but when we run it, it returns an exception saying:

> The property 'ISBN' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The
>   property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a
>   non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type
>   must implement ICollection where T is a valid entity type.

Here are all the relevant classes.

**Book.cs**

```
public partial class Book
{
    [Key, Required]
    [StringLength(14)]
    public string ISBN { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }

    public string Publisher { get; set; }

    public string YearPublished { get; set; }

    public virtual Price Price { get; set; }
}
```

**Price.cs**

```
 public partial class Price
    {
        [Key, Required]
        public int PriceID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ISBN")]
        public string ISBN { get; set; }

        public decimal? AmazonPrice { get; set; }

        public decimal? BarnesAndNoblePrice { get; set; }

        public decimal? CheggPrice { get; set; }

        public decimal? SecondAndCharlesPrice { get; set; }

        public decimal? AlibrisPrice { get; set; }

        public decimal? ThriftBooksPrice { get; set; }

        public decimal? ValoreBooksPrice { get; set; }

        public virtual Book Book { get; set; }

        public virtual IEnumerable<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }
```

**MyModel.cs**

```
public class MyModel : DbContext
{
    public MyModel()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection") { }

    public virtual DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Price> Prices { get; set; }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new IndexVM();
        var ctx = new MyModel();
        foreach (var bk in ctx.Books)
        {
            model.Books.Add(bk);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

We've been told by our professor that it has something to do with the IEnumerable class, but we've tried every combination in the book and we still can't get it to work.

Any and all help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In Price.cs

```
[ForeignKey("ISBN")]
public string ISBN { get; set; }
```

should read

```
[ForeignKey("Book")]
public string ISBN { get; set; }
```

Additionally in Book.cs I think you need somewhere to store the cross reference to Price

```
[ForeignKey("Price")]
public int PriceId { get; set; }
```

this question describes the same issue [Foreign Key Annotation in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765817/foreign-key-annotation-in-mvc)

Comment: Alright, that got rid of that error - I thought the value being passed into the ForeignKey annotation is the actual field of the other class - in this case, would have been "ISBN" from my Book class. I never knew it had to be the name of the class itself.

Now I have a new error though - "Price_Book_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Price_Book_Source' in relationship 'Price_Book'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'."